# About vectors that realize the angle between subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U$ and $V$ be linear subspaces in the Euclidean space  $\mathbb R^n$.
Let $x_1 \in U$ and $y_1\in V$ be unit vectors with respect to the Euclidean norm such that
$$
\langle x_1,y_1\rangle=\max \{\langle x,y\rangle: x\in U, y\in V, \|x\|=1, \|y\|=1 \}. 
$$
I wish to prove that there are positive constants $s,t>0$ such that
$$
P_U(y_1)=tx_1, \ P_V(x_1)=sy_1,
$$
where $P_U$, $P_V$ are orthogonal projections on $U$, $V$, respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $$\langle x,y\rangle =\langle P_Ux,P_Vy\rangle =
 \langle P_VP_Ux,y\rangle,\quad x\in U,\,y\in V$$
Therefore
$$\displaylines{\langle P_VP_Ux_1,y_1\rangle=\langle x_1,y_1\rangle \\ =\max\{\langle P_VP_Ux,y\rangle \,:\, x\in U,\ y\in V,\  \|x\|=\|y\|=1\}\\ =\max\{\langle P_VP_Ux,y\rangle \,:\, \|x\|=\|y\|=1\}=\|P_VP_U\|}$$
Thus
$$\|P_VP_U\|=\langle P_VP_Ux_1,y_1\rangle\le \|P_VP_Ux_1\|\,\|y_1\|\le \|P_VP_U\|\quad (*)$$
This implies
$$\langle P_VP_Ux_1,y_1\rangle =\|P_VP_Ux_1\|\,\|y_1\|$$ i.e. the equality occurs in the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.
Hence $$P_Vx_1=P_VP_Ux_1=ty_1\ \  {\rm for\ some}\ t\ge 0$$
By $(*)$ we get $t=\|P_VP_U\|.$ Switching the roles of $U$ and $V$ gives
$$P_Uy_1=\|P_UP_V\|\, x_1=\|P_VP_U\|\, x_1$$

Comment: Ryszard. Very thanks for your answer.